# System.FormatException after June CU on MOSS 2007

Tags: cumulative-update

Since we have installed the June CU on our farm we get an "Unknown Error" while creating the default groups of a subsite (permsetup.aspx). ULS LogViewer shows me the following Exception: Exception Type: System.FormatException  Exception Message: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.

The error only occurs if a radio button is changed on the permsetup page. If we are taking the default settings (existing group for visitors, new group for members and owners) everything works fine and the groups are created.

Is there a known fix for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in the August 2011 CU.

Answer (score 1):

I received the same error. This is not a fix but a work around:

You can create all the default groups if you clear the default users from the member and owners group. Once removed, add the users you want and the site will be created as normal.

Comment: Well, this seems to work - thank you. A real solution would be great, though.